# How to add Day to JSON array dynamically based on existing date in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I want to add day to the JSON data dynamically based on the Date.  I am using moment(Data.Date).format('dddd') to get the day.

My JSON Data is

```
{
      "Date": "2019/09/12"
    },
    {

      "Date": "2019/09/12"
    },
    {

      "Date": "2019/09/12"
    },
```

I want to insert day like this

```
{
       "Date": "2019/09/12"
      "Day": "Monday"
    },
    {

      "Date": "2019/09/13"
       "Day": "Tuesday"
    },
    {

      "Date": "2019/09/12"
       "Day": "Wednesday"
    },
```

I tried adding Data["Date"]= moment(Data.Date).format('dddd') but it doesn't work.

Comment: `d.getDate()` will get the Day of the Week as a number, 0-6.  You can easily have a a parser which takes the 0-6 and convert it to a string..  daysStringArray = ["Sunday".....], then you can say: `daysStringArray[d.getDate()] || "Not Found"`

Comment: I already have the day value. But not able to add it dynamically to each JSON object.

Comment: `objectList = objectList.map( Data => { Data["Day"] = ....; return Data;})`  What it sounds like is that you are setting the object, but not saving it.  So what the map function is doing is applying all augmentations to each object, then returning this new object.  It will keep preexisting k-v pairs, but add whatever additional ones you may need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you FallenReaper. As per your suggestion in the comment the working code is

Data is the json object array

```
objectList = Data.map( obj => { 
    obj["Day"] = moment(obj.Date,"YYYY/MM/DD").format('dddd'); 

    return obj;})
```

Answer (score 1):

> I tried adding Data["Date"]= moment(Data.Date).format('dddd') but it doesn't work.

It seems that you are overwriting the `Date` property of an object which destroys the previous value of the `Date`. Instead add a new key to each object called `Day` which holds the new value. Loop through the array and modify each object.

Or it could be that you simply try to modify the array which holds all of the objects and nothing happens. Can't tell from your code.

The example below modifies the sample data to add the new `Day` key.

Also consider noting your dates in the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) (year-month-day with dashes instead of slashes) format since this is **a** standard to note dates. It also makes `moment.js` very happy if you do so.

**Sidenote**
If you do not want the original data to be modified consider using the [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method of the array to create a new array from the original JSON data, but with modified keys and values. Like @Fallenreaper suggested

```js
const data = [
  {
    "Date": "2019-09-12"
  },
  {

    "Date": "2019-09-13"
  },
  {

    "Date": "2019-09-14"
  },
];

data.forEach(item => {
  const date = moment(item.Date);
  const day = date.format('dddd');
  item.Day = day;
});

console.log(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    var object = {
      "Date": "2019/09/12"
    }

    object['Day'] = moment(object.Date).format("dddd");

    console.log(object);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: OP says that hey can create the Day of the Week, but it is not preserving it in his object.